# Laravel: how to append to a query if not sure if the clause is needed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Im creating a filtering search system where people can choose which filters to add to their search. I want to be able to add a filter, depending on its EXISTENCE.

So, normally you do a query like this in Laravel:

```
$users = User::where('active', '=', 1)->orWhere('subscribed', '=', 1)->get();
```

But if you dont know whether youre gonna use the `orWhere()` clause. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `User::query()` to fetch the query, then dynamically add clauses according to your app logic:

```
$query = User::query();
if(Request::get('active')){
    $query = $query->whereActive();
}
if(Request::get('subscribed')){
    $query = $query->orWhere('subscribed', 1);
}
return $query->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use where scope to append the where clause:

```
$users = User::where(function($query) use ($subscribed) {
             $query->where('status', 1);
             if ($subscribed)
                 $query->orWhere('subscribed', 1);
         })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear to me but here is an approach:

```
$query = User::where('active', '=', 1);
if ($needSubscribers) {
  $query = $query->orWhere('subscribed', '=', 1);
}
if ($needOtherCriteria) {
  $query = $query->orWhere('filter', '=', 3);
}
$users = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use when a method

```
$users = User::when(condition1, function ($query) {

                $query->where('subscribed', '=', 1);

            })->when(condition2, function ($query) {

                $query->where('filter', '=', 3);

            })->get();
```

Comment: laravel doesnt allow multiple whens